# TailwindCSS - adding fontSize

Tags: tailwind-css

TailwindCSS 1.2.0

What I'm doing wrong? if I add fontSize as below text-7xl doesn't show up as the new optional value and text-6xl disappear.

```js
module.exports = {
    important: true,
    theme: {
        fontFamily: {
            'theme-f1': ['"Oswald"', "sans-serif"],
            'theme-f2': ['"Lora"', "serif"],
            'theme-f3': ['"Bebas Kai"', "sans-serif"],
            'theme-f4': ['"Open Sans"', "sans-serif"],
        },
        fontSize: {
            '7xl': '7rem',
        },
        extend: {
            colors: {
                'theme-c1': '#006c32',
                'theme-c1-b': '#6c8213',
                'theme-c2': '#000000',
                'theme-c3': '#ffffff',
            }
        },
    },
    variants: {
        letterSpacing: ['responsive', 'hover', 'focus'],
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages. We need sufficient code and input to duplicate the problem on our own machines.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Currently you are overriding the default font sizes, you have to extend them if you want to add new font sizes without overriding the default ones:

```
module.exports = {
    important: true,
    theme: {
        fontFamily: {
            'theme-f1': ['"Oswald"', "sans-serif"],
            'theme-f2': ['"Lora"', "serif"],
            'theme-f3': ['"Bebas Kai"', "sans-serif"],
            'theme-f4': ['"Open Sans"', "sans-serif"],
        },
        extend: {
            fontSize: {
                '7xl': '7rem',
            },
            colors: {
                'theme-c1': '#006c32',
                'theme-c1-b': '#6c8213',
                'theme-c2': '#000000',
                'theme-c3': '#ffffff',
            }
        },
    },
    variants: {
        letterSpacing: ['responsive', 'hover', 'focus'],
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

Afterwards compile your assets and you should have the default font sizes  and your custom font size available.

You can read more about extending the default theme in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme/#extending-the-default-theme):

> If you'd like to preserve the default values for a theme option but
>   also add new values, add your extensions under the theme.extend key.
>
> For example, if you wanted to add an extra breakpoint but preserve the
>   existing ones, you could extend the screens property:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // Adds a new breakpoint in addition to the default breakpoints
      screens: {
        '2xl': '1440px',
      }
    }
  }
}
```